# Use Sql Server Compact Edition Database File in ReportViewer .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I have finished a Windows Forms application using Sql Server Compact Edition 4, and .Net Framework 4.0. I want to use the database file to create a report in ReportViewer, but I don't know how to do that, when I try to create a new Datasource in the ReportViewer wizard I have a successful connection, but when I press next, the database file isn't recognized, it says `Error getting database information` and `This selector doesn't accept the specified type`. I have been searching a lot but I just find code fragments that are marked as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a DataSet in code, and use that with the Report Viewer. For a full discussion and link to solution, see https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/issues/39

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved my problem. I'm using 3 layers, using DAL, BLL and presentation layer, I just changed the way I fill the Data Set. Amazing tool by the way, its documentation just need more SEO or something, because I made a lot of search by "sqlce reportviewer" and "sql server compact edition report viewer" and I was never redirected to this site.